# Split the matrix 8-ways PUZZLE

Tags: puzzle, computational-mathematics

I have a problem that has been bugging me for the last month, there is a matrix with 8x8 squares, so 64 squares, and with 8 balls placed randomly each in a square. I need to find the solution of how the matrix should be split into 8 parts such that each ball is in a different part and each part has exactly 8 squares.
By the way, each "puzzle" can have multiple, one, or no solutions.

Before:

[image: 8x8 board with 8 positions marked]

After:

[image: 8x8 board with 8 regions of size 8, each containing a marker]

Comment: Do the parts have to be connected?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean, if you want, you can look on the after link in which is a solved puzzle and you can see that every part is distinguished by a different color.

Comment: You don't say exactly what the requirements are.  If there are no requirements other than what you said, just divide up the $56$ squares with no balls arbitrarily into eight sets of $7$.  Each part consists of one square with a ball and one of the sets of $7$.

Comment: For example, is [this](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/foo.png) a valid solution?  If not, why not?

Comment: Now i get what you've meant, no it's not a valid solution. The parts need to be connected, and a square can be connected only with other one only from up down left or right

Comment: Where did you first encounter this problem?

Comment: The puzzle ["Galaxies"](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/galaxies.html) from Simon Tatham's Portable Puzzle Collection appears to be related and might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy solution.  In principle you could do this, but in practice I doubt that it is realistic:  For each ball $b$, let $S_b$ be the set of all connected sets of cardinality $8$ containing $b$ and no other ball.  Take binary variables $x_i$ for all members $i$ of all $S_b$.  Then you want to satisfy the conditions
$$\eqalign{\sum_{i \in S_b} x_i &= 1\ \text{for each $b$}\cr
           x_i + x_j &\le 1 \ \text{if $x_i \in S_b$ and $x_j \in S_{b'}$ with $b \ne b'$ and $i \cap j \ne \emptyset$}\cr} $$
Use a SAT solver or integer linear programming.

In cases where a solution exists, you might find one using heuristic methods such as tabu search or simulated annealing.

Comment: You can tighten the formulation by replacing the "conflict" constraints with set partitioning constraints for all cells, not just the ones that contain a ball.  You would have the same set of decision variables and 64 equality constraints.  Knuth's dancing links algorithm would likely solve this quickly.

Comment: Indeed, the set partitioning formulation solves instantly even with a generic MILP solver.

Answer (score 0):

You can model this as a set partitioning problem as follows.  Let $S$ be the set of all connected sets of cardinality 8 that contain exactly 1 ball.  For the sample puzzle above, it turns out that $|S|=23617$.  Let $N=\{1,\dots,8\}$.  For $(i,j) \in N \times N$, let $S_{i,j} \subset S$ be the subset of sets that contain cell $(i,j)$.  For $s\in S$, let binary decision variable $x_s$ indicate whether set $s$ is selected.  The constraints are:
$$\sum_{s\in S_{i,j}} x_s = 1 \quad \text{for $(i,j)\in N \times N$}$$

There are multiple solutions, including this one:

> [image]